# PHP prepared statements return null when selecting multiple table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, slim-3

Currently using Slim PHP to do prepared statement.
I am able to retrieve when my query is

```
select * FROM doctor
```

However, once I change to

```
select * FROM doctor d, user u where d.doctor_nric=u.doctor_nric;
```

the system will return me null. 
I already tried on mySQL, it work properly. Any idea which part of my code went wrong?

```
public function getAllDoctor()
{
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("select * FROM doctor d, user u where d.doctor_nric=u.doctor_nric;");
    $stmt ->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt ->bind_result($doctor_nric,$doctor_name,$doctor_contact);
    $doctors = array();

    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $data= array();
        $data['nric']=$doctor_nric;
        $data['name']=$doctor_name;
        $data['contact']=$doctor_contact;
        $data['user_id']=$doctor_id;
        array_push($doctors,$data);
    }

    return $doctors;
}
```

Comment: What you posted doesn't really qualify as a prepared statement. See the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: use `mysqli_error($this->con)` to see why it failed, and enable error reporting

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner did not return any error. I google search around, what I found from others also they using d.doctor_nric=u.doctor_nric way to retrieve at prepared statement

Comment: @beginnerK Please edit your question to include `var_dump()` lines where you output the return value of `->execute();`, `->store_result();` and `->bind_result(...);`. Also output the return value of `$stmt->num_rows` after the `->store_result()` to see the number of rows returned. Then at the end add a `var_dump($doctors);` to see the array you built before leaving this method. Btw.: you haven't bound `$doctor_id` and you should replace `*` with the columns you want to read.

Comment: @Progman I tried your method, is the *  that cause all my query not retrieve properly! Thanks alot ! I solved this issues.